# How to modify error message after executing a command via a Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-task

I'm implementing a Gradle Java plugin which registers below task.

```
TaskProvider<Exec> taskProvider = project.getTasks().register("spectralTask", Exec.class);
taskProvider.configure(exec -> {
    exec.executable("spectral");
    exec.args("lint");
});
```

When the output of the executed command is an error, this is what I get.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:spectralTask'.
> Process 'command 'spectral'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This error message is not very helpful. I want to fix it.
Is there a way to do below?

1. Print a custom error message.
2. Print the exact error message given by the executed command.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this one option is to overwrite exec's standardOutput and/or errorOutput with `ByteArrayOutputStream` and re-throwing the exception with modified message from it.

For example:

```
def execOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
try {
    return this.project.exec({
        it.errorOutput = execOutput
        it.standardOutput = execOutput       
        // rest of exec's config
    })
} catch (exception) {
    // Will print task's output as part of the error message
    throw new ExecException(exception.message + LineSeparator.SYSTEM + execOutput.toString())
} finally {
    // Preserve the logs in the task output
    print execOutput.toString()
}
```